# How avoid stack overflow with tail and trampoline in recursion function?

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming

I write the program to pass the quiz -https://www.codewars.com/kata/53d045892578b1be8b0001c4, but it still not work with big numbres. Where is my mistake ?

```js
function thunk(fn, n, ac) {
  return fn(n, ac);
}

function trampoline(arg) {
  // console.log(arg);
  if (typeof arg === "number") {
    return arg;
  } else {
    return trampoline(arg);
  }
}

function trampolineSum(n) {
  function _sum(n, ac) {
    if (n === 0) {
      return ac;
    } else {
      return thunk(_sum, n - 1, ac + n);
    }
  }

  return trampoline(thunk(_sum, n, 0));
}

console.log(trampolineSum(4444));
console.log(trampolineSum(44444));
```

Comment: Where is the loop inside your "trampoline"?

Comment: Hello bob , `function trampoline(arg) {
  // console.log(arg);
  if (typeof arg === "number") {
    return arg;
  } else {
    arg = arg()
    return trampoline(arg);
  }
}` still not work

Comment: that's not a loop. that's still recursion.  and thunk isn't doing anything   read the instructions: "trampoline(thunk) is a function that executes repeatedly the thunk argument until it returns a non function value. Then this last value is returned."

Comment: user120242  , can you show a small example how it must be ?

Comment: My favorite thing about this code challenge is that the output can literally be calculated as `n(n+1)/2` and doesn't even require recursion in the first place lol

Comment: @Christian doesn't require iteration at all you mean

Comment: Btw, you need the loop (and the entire trampoline respectively), because there is no tail recursion optimization in Javascript, even though it is specified.

Comment: [Proper Tail Calls Kangax Compatibility Table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-proper_tail_calls_%28tail_call_optimisation%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is broken on purpose and missing things.  Try to figure it out.
[Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

thunk(fn /*, args */) is a function that receives a function and possibly some arguments to be passed to the function **and returns a function**. When this returned function is called, it returns the result of execute the fnfunction. In functional programming, a thunk is a deferred expression (function). Its evaluation is postponed until it's really needed.

trampoline(thunk) is a function that **executes repeatedly the thunk** argument until it returns a non function value. Then this last value is returned.

```js
function thunk(fn, n, ac) {
  return ???.bind(null, n, ac);
}

const trampoline = res => {
  I_WANT_TO_LOOP (typeof res === 'function') { res = res(); }
  return res;
}

function trampolineSum(n) {
  function _sum(n, ac) {
    if (n === 0) {
      return ac;
    } else {
      return thunk(_sum, n - 1, ac + n);
    }
  }

  return trampoline(thunk(_sum, n, 0));
}

console.log(trampolineSum(4444));
console.log(trampolineSum(44444));
```

Comment: So you can try to learn yourself and figure it out.  Doesn't it become pointless if I do it for you?

Comment: I think it would be cleaner if `thunk` constructed a closure with a function expression around the call to do than to use `bind`

Comment: `  return fn.bind(null, n, ac);
}

const trampoline = res => {
  while (typeof res === 'function') { res = res(); }

Comment: It was interesting quiz )

Comment: GJ, go try and see if you can do what Bergi just said too, and see what he means

Comment: Bergi , you mean like this : `function thunk(fn, n, ac) {
  let boundFn = fn.bind(null, n, ac)
  return boundFn;
}`

Comment: no, fn.bind returns a function. read the linked article explaining bind.  it is returning a function with this=null, and two arguments n, ac bound to it.  Bergi is saying you should use and return an anonymous function closure to wrap the fn() call instead of using bind

Comment: search google for "function closures javascript".  that segment of code you just posted, is technically a function closure

Comment: `function thunk(fn, n, ac) {
  return ()=>{
   return  fn(n,ac)
  }
}` Like this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small adaptation of your original code -

```js
function thunk(fn, n, ac) {
  return [ thunk, _ => fn(n, ac) ]
}

function trampoline(r) {
  while (r && r[0] === thunk)
    r = r[1]()
  return r
}

function trampolineSum(n) {
  function _sum(n, ac) {
    if (n === 0) {
      return ac;
    } else {
      return thunk(_sum, n - 1, ac + n);
    }
  }

  return trampoline(thunk(_sum, n, 0));
}

console.log(trampolineSum(4444)) // 9876790
console.log(trampolineSum(44444)) // 987656790
```

Consider alternate implementations -

```js
const recur = (...v) =>
  ({ recur, [Symbol.iterator]: _ => v.values() })

const loop = f =>
{ let r = f()
  while (r && r.recur === recur)
    r = f(...r)
  return r
}

const trampolineSum = n =>
  loop
    ( (m = n, ac = 0) =>
        m === 0
          ? ac
          : recur(m - 1, ac + m)
    )

console.log(trampolineSum(4444)) // 9876790
console.log(trampolineSum(44444)) // 987656790
```